# SOAP fault in gSoap client

Tags: c++, web-services, exchangewebservices, gsoap, soapfault

I'm trying to send a message to exchange server using EWS with gSoap. what i have done is:

1. Set SSL Connection and Auth. with Exchange Server. (This works fine)
2. Define createItem operation to create message.
3. Set the receiver info.
4. Define MessageDispositionType to define type for sendOnly message.
5. Send CreateItem request to server.

After successful compilation, I have following SOAP fault when run the program (for SOAP version 1.2)

```
 SOAP 1.2 fault: SOAP-ENV:Sender[ns2:ErrorSchemaValidation] "The request failed schema validation: The element 'Items' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages' has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected: 'Item, Message, CalendarItem, Contact, DistributionList, MeetingMessage, MeetingRequest, MeetingResponse, MeetingCancellation, Task, ReplyToItem, ForwardItem, ReplyAllToItem, AcceptItem, TentativelyAcceptItem, DeclineItem, CancelCalendarItem, RemoveItem, SuppressReadReceipt' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types'." Detail: ErrorSchemaValidation/e:ResponseCode
```

And after successful compilation, I have following SOAP fault when run the program (for SOAP version 1.1)

```
SOAP 1.1 fault: SOAP-ENV:MustUnderstand[no subcode] "The data in element 'Action' must be understood but cannot be handled" Detail: [no detail]
```

What could be possible problem it is? Any help appreciated. thank you.

Comment: I've found this https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c181948e-6d3b-4c31-8111-8cb4ee02efe1/gsoap-client-and-wcf-webservice-incompatibility-in-action-tag?forum=wcf , but problem remains same.